# ember.js | notify other components on one component action

Tags: ember.js

in the [components section at Ember's guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/handling-user-interaction-with-actions/) there a demo of *Post Summary Component*,
clicking on one Post Summery title opens its content below it.

I would like to add the functionality to close any other opened Post summaries at the same time.

**The purpose on my question is the understand how ember speaks between components without sacrificing isolation.**

the solutions I thought about are:

1. have some wrapper component that handles it in some way
2. firing an event like 'post-summery:open' and make other components close themselves on it (but then it can Collide with other places on the app using the same components for diffecnt uses)

this is the original demo from the documentation:
http://jsbin.com/uyibis/1/edit

This is how I would Implement the behavior with jQuery:
http://jsbin.com/eremon/2/edit

> var $contents = $('.content').hide();
>
> $(document).on('click', '.title', function () {
>
> $contents.hide();
>     $(this).next('.content').show();
>
> });

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Ember.Component` you don't have the control of the childViews, so I used the `Ember.CollectionView`, to manage the items. Because `App.PostSummaryComponent` already extends `Ember.Component`, I delegate to the `Ember.CollectionView` that behavior using `view containerViewClass` in the template. So we have the best of the two worlds.

Since that `containerViewClass` property is a class, we need a way to access that instance - to interact with the `childViews` - when the view is created. To do this you have to use `viewName='containerView'` in the template. This tells Ember, that a new instance of `containerViewClass` will be setted in a property called  `containerView`. So we can use `this.get("containerView")` in `App.PostSummaryComponent`.

The last change was moving the `each` helper from index template to the component template. So others calls to the component doesn't need to repeat it.

http://jsbin.com/ebayip/2/edit

Comment: could you please explain what you have done?
especially, what is the connection between this.get("containerView") and containerViewClass?
thank you.

Comment: @TreeFlute I updated the aswer. My english isn't good, so if you have some doubt. Please give me know.

Answer (score 5):

This problem comes up all the time in Ember. The way I solve it is to keep track of which post is "open" on the controller and then have each item's view be responsible for its own state based on that data. That way you don't have to manually reset every post's state each time you toggle one.

The canonical source of truth is the controller.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: null,
    selectedPost: null // null means no post selected
});
```

We wire this information to the components through the template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each post in controller}}
        {{post-summary post=post selectedPost=selectedPost}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/post-summary">
    <h3 {{action "toggleBody"}}>{{post.title}}</h3>
    {{#if isShowingBody}}
        <p>{{{post.body}}}</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Now the body visibility for a given post can be computed by a property.

```
App.PostSummaryComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    post: null,
    selectedPost: null,

    isShowingBody: function() {
        return this.get('selectedPost') === this.get('post');
    }.property('selectedPost', 'post'),

    toggleBody: function() {
        this.set('selectedPost', 
                 this.get('isShowingBody') ? null : this.get('post'));
    }    
});
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/K5b4v/).

One could argue that this isn't an ideal object-oriented solution, but it has drastically improved the structure and maintainability of my Ember apps. You can implement a wide variety of complex list behaviours by having each element responsible for its own state based on a common source of truth.